# Flutter forLoop to Json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have this for loop that should return some json parameters:

```
Map<String, dynamic> items2 = {};
Set<Map<String, dynamic>> filedNamesValues;
```

This is the loop:

```
 filedNamesValues = {for(int i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++)
      items2 = {
        fieldNames[i] : controllers[i].text
      }
  };
```

and when you `print(filedNamesValues.toList());` it prints the fields the I need down below:

```
[
   {
      "inputone":"value"
   },
   {
      "inputtxt":"value"
   },
   {
      "inputdob":"value"
   },
   {
      "inputdo":"value"
   },
   {
      "inpuno":"value"
   }
]
```

However I want them to be like this:

```
[
   {
      "inputone":"value",
      "inputtxt":"value",
      "inputdob":"value",
      "inputdo":"value",
      "inpuno":"value"
   }
]
```

What am i missing ? Some help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What will be shown if you print `[items2]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change this:

```
 filedNamesValues = {for(int i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++)
   items2 = {
    fieldNames[i] : controllers[i].text
   }   
 };
```

for this:

```
 filedNamesValues = {for(int i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++)
   items2.addAll({"${fieldNames[i]}":controllers[i].text});
 };
```

Comment: When i try it it say "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used." for the .addAll and does not even let me run it.

Comment: Change the initialization of the Map for Map<String, dynamic> items2 = <String, dynamic>{};

Comment: that TOTALY worked, but I had to do it like this:   for(int i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
      items2.addAll({"${fieldNames[i]}":controllers[i].text});
  }.....without the "filedNamesValues = " and just print the items2 
NOTE* i did not need to change the initialization of the Mmap